# Android json parsing error in http response

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I'm calling http request in android using volley, but sometimes I get JSON parsing error when receiving the response, even though the response is always the same.

```
void login() throws JSONException {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = String.format("%s/login", getString(R.string.url));
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("email", etEmail.getText().toString());
    data.put("password", etPassword.getText().toString());
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.POST, url, data, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Helper.unblockUI(pb, getWindow());
                try{
                    if(response.has("error")){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else if(response.has("id") && response.has("token")){
                        enterMainActivity();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Something is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    Helper.unblockUI(pb, getWindow());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Helper.unblockUI(pb, getWindow());
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });

    Helper.blockUI(pb, getWindow());
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

and the response is:

`{"error":"Email doesn't exist"}`

when the response goes like that it doesn't error because that is valid JSON,
I don't know why but sometimes the response is like this:

`{"error":"Email doesn't exist"`

it's minus one brace in the end, so volley response is error because that is not valid JSON.

any idea why this is happening? because sometime it got valid json and sometime it doesn't, I always return the same response from the api but sometime the response is minus one braces in the end of json object..

Output when successful:
`2018-10-09 21:05:22.717 12545-12545/com.omg_indo.itmsapp D/tag: {"error":"Email doesn't exist"}`

Output when error:
`2018-10-09 21:08:02.019 12545-12545/com.omg_indo.itmsapp D/tag: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 30 of {"error":"Email doesn't exist"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of your issue, but you could try using a global singleton request queue instead of creating a new local one in your method. To do that, you would keep the `RequestQueue` as a member variable in your `Application` class.

```
class MyApplication extends Application{


    private static MyApplication sInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return sInstance;
    }


    public synchronized RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if( mRequestQueue == null )
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        return mRequestQueue;
    }


}
```

And then you would use it like this

```
MyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add( jsonObjectRequest );
```

That would keep the request queue around for the lifetime of your application.

[The documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue) is a little bit ambiguous on this though - at one point they say

> A key concept is that the RequestQueue must be instantiated with the Application context, not an Activity context. This ensures that the RequestQueue will last for the lifetime of your app, instead of being recreated every time the activity is recreated (for example, when the user rotates the device).

But they also say

> If you just need to make a one-time request and don't want to leave the thread pool around, you can create the RequestQueue wherever you need it and call stop() on the RequestQueue once your response or error has come back, using the Volley.newRequestQueue() method [...]

which is what you're currently doing, and what I've done in several projects and never had any issues with. But it's worth trying to move to the singleton pattern for your request queue and see if that solves your issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried your method, but still.. sometime it's received valid JSON Object and sometime it's received JSON Object with minus braces in the end that makes parsing error..